# Passing a string from a structure to an array of strings - C

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
typedef struct mensagem
{
    int sender ;
    int receiver ;
    char *text ;
} *Item ;

typedef struct node
{
    Item item ;
    struct node *next ;
} *link ;

typedef struct queue
{
    link head, tail ;
    int size ;
} *Queue ;

     void listsorted(Queue list)
    {
        Queue temp = list ;
        int s=temp->size ;
        char *sorted ;
        int i=0;

        sorted = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));

        while ( i < s )
        {
            strcpy( sorted[i] , list->head->item->text ) ;
            list->head = list->head->next ;
            i++ ;
        }

        i=0;

        for ( i=0 ; i<s ; i++ )
        {
            printf("%s\n", sorted[i] ) ;
        }
    }
```

I want to sort alphabeticaly a queue, so I thought to copy the strings to an array and qsort that array. But i'm not even managing to make the array with the strings. I get an error on the strcpy . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what error exactly are you getting?  Is it at compile-time or at run-time?

Comment: Compile error on the first argument of strcpy

Comment: I think it should be `char **sorted`; cause you want to have an array of strings.

Comment: That solves it in the compiler, but i get a segmentation fault when i enter the while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not malloc()'ing both dimensions of the array. Take a look at the following code (untested):

```
 void listsorted(Queue list)
{
    Queue temp = list ;
    int s=temp->size ;
    char **sorted ; /* Changed here */
    int i=0;

    sorted = malloc((s + 1) * sizeof(char *)); /* Changed here */

    while ( i < s )
    {
        sorted[i] = malloc(strlen(list->head->item->text) + 1); /* Changed here */
        strcpy( sorted[i] , list->head->item->text ) ;
        list->head = list->head->next ;
        i++ ;
    }
    sorted[i] = NULL; /* Changed here. NULL terminate array */

    i=0;

    for ( i=0 ; i<s ; i++ )
    {
        printf("%s\n", sorted[i] ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: It compiles, but it is only printing the first string.
EDIT: Nevermind, that was due to a problem in another part of the code, so it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`sorted[i]` is of type char, not of type char*.  That's because you're only allocating a one-dimensional array (i.e., a string) and not a two-dimensional array (i.e., an array of strings).  Further, you're `malloc`ing 1 byte then attempting to copy the contents of `list->head->item->text` into it.  This will be bad news even if you get this code to compile.

Make sure you always allocate the correct amount of memory, and make sure you always use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`.